# How to write the following in Linq or Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, t-sql

Appreciate if I can get some help writing a LINQ that will get ALL FIELDS from table A, and those fields for which profile 1 has a value in table AB, show the value, otherwise if profile 1 has no entry in table AB, then show value as null.

Table A

```
AID    Field
-----------
1      OneField
2      TwoField
3      ThreeField
```

Table B

```
BID    Value
-----------
1      OneValue
2      TwoValue
3      ThreeValue
```

Table AB

```
ABID   AID   BID  ProfileId
-------------------------
1      1     1    1
2      2     3    1
```

I'm trying to write a Linq (or sql query) that will show me for profile id 1, all the values from table a, and for those that apply, the value from table b.

e.g.

```
ProfileID  AID       Field        BID       Value
--------------------------------------------------------
1          1         OneField     1         OneValue
1          2         TwoField     3         ThreeValue
1          3         ThreeField   NULL      NULL
```

As you can see, the aim is to get ALL FIELDS from table A, and those fields for which profile 1 has an entry in table AB, show the value from table B, otherwise if profile 1 has no entry in table AB, then show as null.

If the solution requires it, I am happy to write that in sql and call it via stored proc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working LINQ solution with a full self contained test.  I did not add any asserts at the end but the variable at the end "queryResult" will contain a list with the result you desire. I tested it and verified that it works.  Here is the code:

**Edit: In response to your comment Here is example #2**

```
    public class tablea
    {
        public int AID { get; set; }
        public string Field { get; set; }
    }
    public class tableb
    {
        public int BID { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class tableab
    {
        public int ProfileID { get; set; }
        public int AID { get; set; }
        public string Field { get; set; }
        public int BID { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class result
    {
        public int? profileid { get; set; }
        public int? aid { get; set; }
        public string field { get; set; }
        public string bid { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestQuery()
    {
        var tablea = new List<tablea>();
        var tableb = new List<tableb>();
        var tableab = new List<tableab>();

        tablea.Add(new tablea{AID = 1,Field = "OneField"});
        tablea.Add(new tablea{AID = 2,Field = "TwoField"});
        tablea.Add(new tablea{AID = 3,Field = "ThreeField"});

        tableb.Add(new tableb{BID = 1,Value = "OneValue"});
        tableb.Add(new tableb{BID = 2,Value = "TwoValue"});
        tableb.Add(new tableb{BID = 3,Value = "ThreeValue"});

        tableab.Add(new tableab{AID = 1,BID=1,ProfileID = 1});
        tableab.Add(new tableab{AID = 2,BID=3,ProfileID = 1});

        var profileId = 1;

        var q1 = (from a in tablea
                  let bid = (from ab in tableab where ab.ProfileID == profileId && ab.AID == a.AID select ab.BID).FirstOrDefault()
                  let value = (from ab in tableab where ab.ProfileID == profileId && ab.AID == a.AID && ab.BID == bid select ab.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                select new result
                            {
                                profileid = profileId,
                                aid = a.AID,
                                field = a.Field,
                                bid = (bid == 0 ? "null" : bid.ToString()),
                                value = value ?? "null"
                           }).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Hi Roberto. Thanks for this, it works pretty good in the unit test. However against linq2sql entities, the DefaultIfEmpty fails because the values passed in the default if empty have fk constrainsts on them and I get the exception "System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object". Bummer. I will keep trying and post when i find a solution.
thanks.

Comment: damn... so close.  unfortunately I don't use LINQ to SQL, so I don't know it's limitations.  Unfortunately if you return null for DefaultIfEmpty then the rest of the query will fail because it is trying to access properties on that returned object....

Comment: Thanks Roberto. This has pointed me in the right direction. I will keep trying. marking yours as the accepted answer for its thoroughness. +1 for doing a full self-contained test.

Comment: The sql generated by linq does 4 sub-queries to return the desired data. At some point I will profile it to see if there is an need to  optimise that, but for now I am really happy :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested):

```
SELECT ProfileID, A.AID, Field, B.BID, Value 
FROM AB 
LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON AB.AID = A.AID
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON AB.BID = B.BID
```

Comment: Didn't bring back row 3. This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want ALL ROWS from table A, you need to start with table A:

```
SELECT AB.ProfileID, A.AID, A.Field, B.BID, B.Value 
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN AB ON AB.AID = A.AID
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON AB.BID = B.BID
WHERE (AB.ProfileID = 1 OR AB.ProfileID IS NULL)
```

If you start with table AB in your query, you'll only ever get what's in table AB - and row #3 has no entry in table AB.

Marc

Comment: Thanks marc, but it still is not quite there because if I have more than 1 profile in table AB, and profile 2 AID = 3, then the left outer join on B does not work. Profileid 1 returns 2 records and profileid 2 returns 3. I think it is missing the record because ProfileID will not be null when some other profile uses AID=3.

Comment: one of the main problems here is that you're trying to select on the profileID, but you want to select more than is available in the "AB" join table - that makes it really hard......

Comment: Could you just add **ALL** rows you want to select including their ProfileID into the "AB" table and just leave the "BID" column empty for those that don't have a "B" entity associated?? That way, you could select from the AB join table and use the "ProfileID = x" WHERE clause

Comment: yeah i thought about adding into ab as well, but there already are records in the ab table. therefore lest i write a trigger, inserting values in table a will not automatically insert these values for all profiles into table ab. Trying to think of a clean way to do this...

Comment: Perhaps i should just take the hit and run multiple queries, one to get all the fields, and one to get all the values for profileid 1, and join in code rather than in sql.

Answer (score 0):

[code]
var result = from a  in a
             join ab in ab on a.aid equals ab.aid into tmp1
         join b  in b  on b.id  equals ab.bid into tmp2
         from c in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()  /* this is to get the null values */
         from d in tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new 
        {
         c.ProfileID,
         a.AID,
         a.Field,
                 c.bid,
         d.Value
        };
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

See the example below:

```
var result = from a  in a
             join ab in ab on a.aid equals ab.aid into tmp1
         join b  in b  on b.id  equals ab.bid into tmp2
         from c in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()  /* this is to get the null values */
         from d in tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new 
        {
         c.ProfileID,
         a.AID,
         a.Field,   
                 c.bid,
         d.Value
        };
```

Comment: Thanks! You could also *edit* your own posts and change them - now that you've added a second one, why don't you delete the first one with the non-formatted code snippet.....

Comment: Marc thanks for helping me out but ia m afraid i dont see a delete button

Comment: Hi Edwards, thanks for the post. For some reason, Visual Studio does not like the second join following the line with the first join. Am i missing something?

Comment: Hi Ash are you using linq to entities or linq to SQL

Comment: I am using linq 2 sql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SQL version looks like this

```
select TableA.*, TableB.*
from TableA
    left outer join TableC on TableA.ID = Aid
    left outer join TableB on TableB.id = Bid
where
    TableC.ProfileID = 1
    or TableC.ProfileID is null
```

The outer join ensures you get results from TableA even if there are no matching records on the other side of the join. You have to allow for null values in ProfileID too as a result.